# App controlling home button in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

Just a quick question. Is it by any chance possible, that I can make an app control the users Home-button?

What I want to achieve is, that I want to ask the user if it is OK, that I add a functionality, when they click the Home-button 4 times. Is that even possible - even if the user accepts?

Comment: No. and it won't be useful. I don't want to tap crazy and wear my home button to just use your function.

Comment: Hehe, you actually don't know if you would. But ok, that answers my question, thanks. :)

Comment: You can make an inference that its been tapped once while your app is active because you'll get an aboutToResignActive signal, but that's it.  (and @BryanChen - maybe he was planning to pay users $1000 each time they do this gesture... that would certainly be worth it).